# iOS6, shareSheet - iOS, xCode, Twitter, Facebook UIButton - design

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, twitter, ios6

I'm looking for Facebook and Twitter design Button. I saw a few Apps with nice looking Button-design (original CI). Are these Buttons available anywhere?
They should looks like the default iOS Apps for Facebook and Twitter.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The "Share" ViewController, like it's shown in some iOS6 demo's is not in the new Ap, isn't it?

Comment: [Facebook icon for iPhone app](http://iosicongallery.com/social/facebook/) [Twitter icon iOS](http://ios.twitter.com/) Also, don't forget to review the Developer permissions for use of the Facebook and Twitter brand.

Comment: Hey, Thanks! Thinking about using an ActionSheet with simple "Tweet", "Share on Facebook", "Mail" Functionality. So there's definetely no copyright problem.

Comment: Ask on Apple's dev forums the NDA is until the 19th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you will find some freebies: http://dribbble.com/shots/362856-Facebook-Button-Freebie or here: http://dribbble.com/shots/162195-Facebook-Connect-Buttons-PSD or here: http://dribbble.com/shots/170014-Sign-in-buttons-PSD